# Unable to get the middle row using limit and offset in an unordered table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the middle row of the sorted table. I am using the query:

```
select lat_n, count(*) c from station order by lat_n limit 1, c/2
```

I am getting an error:

> ERROR 1327 (42000) at line 9: Undeclared variable: c

Now, I know there exists a method of ranking the rows or numbering them and then on that basis I can get the middle row but I wanted to know why my method is failing?

The table is taken from [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem).

Comment: I see at least four errors in your query. One of them is quite clearly explained in the error message.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel what are those four(or other 3) errors?

Comment: 1) You can't select `lat_n` if you also select `count(*)` without a GROUP BY clause - It just doesn't make sense and will raise an error on current MySQL versions with default settings. 2) If you select `count(*)` without GROUP BY you will get only one row. So LIMIT makes no sense. 3) `LIMIT 1, c/2` would be equivalent to `LIMIT c/2 OFFSET 1`. You probably want them the other way around. 4) You can't use a column alias as limit or offset. 5) You can't use expressions (calculations) as LIMIT or OFFSET. Only constants or variables are permitted. ... So that are actually 5 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have five errors in your query. From my own comment:

1. You can't select `lat_n` if you also select `count(*)` without a GROUP BY clause - It just doesn't make sense and will raise an error on current MySQL versions with default settings.
2. If you select `count(*)` without GROUP BY you will get only one row. So LIMIT makes no sense.
3. `LIMIT 1, c/2` would be equivalent to `LIMIT c/2 OFFSET 1`. You probably want them the other way around.
4. You can't use a column alias as limit or offset.
5. You can't use expressions (calculations) as LIMIT or OFFSET. Only constants or (local) variables are permitted.

If you want to solve this using LIMIT, you would either need to write a stored procedure or function, where you precalculate the middle position and save it into a local variable:

```
delimiter //

create procedure my_proc ()
begin
  declare c int;

  set c = (select floor(count(*)/2) from station);

  select lat_n
  from station
  order by lat_n
  limit c, 1;

end //

delimiter ;
```

Then execute it with

```
call my_proc();
```

Or you save the position into a user/session variable, and reuse it in a prepared statement:

```
set @c = (select floor(count(*)/2) from station);

set @sql = '
  select lat_n
  from station
  order by lat_n
  limit 1
  offset ?
';

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt using @c;
```

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5JBG9eV3X7kM4RfxhyYFnX/0)

Comment: Thank you so much @Paul!